# How can I remove the 'Possible Duplicate' from a question I asked?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-suggestions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276002/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-a-group-by-clause-without-a-subquery-in-sql-ser), and I specifically detailed in the answer that I needed to do it without a subquery over the full table. I am looking for a way to do it like MySQL does, or use a library that has GROUP_CONCAT() built in as an aggregate function, or if I have to a custom C# CLR .dll. I even outlined why I cannot use a subquery / "The usual workaround for SQL Server" and showed that it would take 4 years to complete.

Someone commented pointing to a 'similar question' that only has subqueries as the answer. I again explained that I was looking for a solution without subqueries. I then got my question downvoted (likely by that user).

Now, despite my efforts, there is a 'Possible Duplicate' banner at the top, again linking to the answer with subqueries. I have edited my question to make it clear both in the title AND in the first sentence that subqueries are unacceptable.

How can I remove the 'Possible Duplicate' banner, or if I need more rep ask it to be removed?

[How can I concatenate strings in a GROUP BY clause without a subquery in SQL Server without an additional query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276002/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-a-group-by-clause-without-a-subquery-in-sql-ser)

Comment: If its not closed yet, only you see it.

Comment: Even so, can't I respond with "No, it isn't?" Won't moderators see it?

Comment: The question doesn't have any __Close Votes__.  Looks like somebody _flagged_ this as a duplicate.

Comment: .... but there's nothing I can do or say about it?

Comment: nothing at all. that is the sense behind it, because sometimes OP can't distinguish correctly, if something is a dupe or not

Comment: In that case, I feel it would be appropriate to let the OP at least explain why it is not a duplicate with a comment or something.

Comment: There's nothing you can do until it expires or gets closed. At most you could include why its not a dupe.

Comment: The flag expires? How long does that take?

Comment: In my experience, if it's really a dupe, do nothing (or even vote close yourself if you agree). If you're convinced it's not a dupe, a simple comment saying "I don't believe it's a dupe because that asks for X and I'm asking for Y which are subtly different" is usually enough to stop others vote closing without checking in detail.

Comment: You can ask mods to disassociate you from your question, if all you want is to get rid of it from a list of questions you asked ;). Probably they will not, but it's the only way to get rid of it from your list. More probably if your overall stats are good.

Comment: Alright, well I already did that in the comments. I don't want to be disassociated, I just want the flag gone.

Comment: I find it funny how this question got marked as duplicate...

Comment: It is rather ironic... but here goes: "I don't believe this is a duplicate because this question is about the duplicate flag and not the already answered one. Someone searching about duplicates specifically should see this question and will likely not pull up the already answered one."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question hasn't been closed as a duplicate, the comment itself has not resulted in the question being closed at this time. If the question is actually a duplicate, then it will be closed. If you don't believe it is a duplicate, reply to the comment on your question with something along the lines of;

> I don't think this question is a duplicate because of `<reasons>`

This will allow people who view the question as a result of the proposed "closing it as a duplicate" to form their own opinion on whether or not it is a duplicate, and vote to close or leave it open accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The message at the top of the question is visible **only to you**, it would only be visible to others if it was actually closed as a duplicate by five 3k+users (or one mod), at present it has zero close votes on it.

Consider it a helpful suggestion, if it isn't helpful just ignore it. (although if the flag is declined then the message will go away even for you).

In this case you have done exactly the right thing; it appeared to others that this might be a duplicate but it wasn't so you clarified your question to show that it is not