# How to post a "Possible duplicate of [QUESTION]" comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, duplicate-suggestions

I often see someone post a comment saying "Possible duplicate of [another question]" and then a dialog shows right under the title of my question asking me if the supplied question has answered mine. How does such a comment work and how do I post one?

Comment: If you flag or VTC it as a duplicate, such comments automatically appear, and to the OP, the dialog always is always shown.

Comment: [Like this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210120/how-can-i-remove-the-possible-duplicate-from-a-question-i-asked?rq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How does such a comment work and how do I post one?

Such comments are automatically applied if the question was close flagged / voted for the *duplicate* reason. There are generally two ways to place them at a question:

1. If a user is below 3,000 reputation, they can flag it and choose *duplicate* from the pop-up dialogue.
2. If a user has close voting privileges (3,000+ rep), they can click the *close* link and choose *duplicate* from the pop-up dialogue.

A manually constructed comment would not have the same effect, but the proposed link will appear in the *Linked* section beneath the question.

---

If the asker accepts the dialogue you've mentioned, the question will be immediately closed by *Community ♦︎*.

Otherwise it takes 5 users with the close voting privilege, a gold badge holder for one of the question's tags, or a moderator to mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: Note that if a comment (even a manually written one) containing a link to the proposed dupe already exists, the "possible duplicate" one won't be generated when somebody flags/vtc's. The existing one will just be upvoted.