# Weird duplicate "Possible duplicate of" comment

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close

As I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432613/insert-item-in-list-alphabetically), two people voted to close it as duplicate. Before the question was closed (and the vote-to-close comments deleted), there were two close vote comments. The first had the following style:

> Possible duplicate of *[Insert an item into sorted list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python)*.

The one below it, which was upvoted, had this text (notice the lack of italics in the link):

> Possible duplicate of [Insert an item into sorted list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python).

However, as per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295337/how-to-post-a-possible-duplicate-of-question-comment#comment958196_295344), the second comment should have never been posted.

1. Why was the second comment posted, and upvoted? Why wasn't the first one upvoted?
2. What's with the difference in italics between the comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first comment was created manually.  The person who posted it just... commented it. Even without access to the timeline, you can tell because the question title is in italics (as you note) and we don't style the auto comments that way. They didn't flag or vote to close the question.

Later, someone else saw the comment and agreed and then actually voted to close the question as a duplicate... and so that comment was the one linked to the voting to close, thusly upvoted.

Comment: I see. Why was the first one deleted if it wasn't an actual vote to close?

Comment: A guess... because our deletion script is slightly smarter than the comment creation script? Or... dumber... It can be a bit aggressive at times.

Comment: @MichaelKolber The auto-deletion targets any comment that links to the duplicate, regardless of formatting or how much other text is surrounding it. So if you wrote a full paragraph talking about the duplicate, we sometimes lose valuable content from that too.

Comment: I would call the auto-deletion script passive-aggressive ...

Comment: @animuson Interesting, is that something to consider fixing?